# Best practices for Facebook integration using the graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

When it comes to integrating your site with facebook, is it recommended to save all the user's info from Facebook to your DB, or is it recommended to query in real time all the info you need based on the user's id?

For example the avatar sizes are different on my site than on my facebook, so I may have no choice but to download the fb avatar, but for other things like name, gender, hometown, I was wondering if I need to save that data.

Also, if I decide to change extended permissions at a later time, is that going to be an easy task?

Answer (score 0):

The choice of whether to cache or re-query is totally dependent on your requirements.  If you absolutely need the name to be exact then you should re-query every time.  I worked on an facebook application that just didn't care about most user details so we didn't even store them let alone cache them.

Extending permissions is pretty easy.